# How does pySpark read data from Cassandra

Tags: python, pyspark, cassandra

My Cassandra runs on a docker container on my machine. And I have a python file who runs the most basic word count application on spark which works. Now I'm trying to read data from my Cassandra. However I didn't find a tutoriel or a example that actually works for my case. I'm trying to avoid using pyspark shell.

So anyone can give me some guide or a website that catually introduce how to access data in Cassandra with PySpark?

Comment: https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/15_python.md

Comment: can you tell me how are you trying to connect with Cassandra database from your simple python code? and also paste you `Dockerfile`